# Is Google Colab supported by C languge?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is Google Colab supported by C languge ? How to run a program written by C in Google Colab enviroment ?

Comment: Not yet.  They support R, Scala, and Julia, all of which use an interpreter.  That's easier to control

Answer (score 0):

Here's my example notebook that run C++. It compiles and runs, but not interactively.

https://colab.to/12usDwskyy71Sc1FpwmvPswID15M51LBH

You can adapt it for C as well.